# QGIS 3.4 - Find all layers not using the project CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I have a large project and I recently reorganised my data. This included reprojecting some of it. I have updated the data sources for all of my layers however there are some layers which are still using the old CRS.

Is there a way to identify all layers in my project which are not using the project CRS? Or else to list all layers using a specific CRS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run this snippet in Qgis python console, it will print all layers name that have a different CRS than the current project:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()

for layer in layers.values():
    if layer.crs() != QgsProject.instance().crs() and layer.dataProvider().name() != 'wms':
        print(layer.name())
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. As an extra is there a way to exclude WMS layers?

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate to the PyQGIS solution provided, the [Layer Board](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LayerBoard/) plug-in summarizes key layer attributes across all layers in a table, CRS included. Quite helpful after reorganizing a project since you can see other properties as well, and also remove ghost layers.